# Unable to connect to Azure Databricks SQL from Azure functions endpoint on Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-databricks

I have developed Azure Function project library using VS 2022. I am accessing a table in Azure Databricks SQL via Apach Spark ODBC driver connection settings. I am able to connect to table and run the HTTP function endpoint locally (e.g. localhost). But after publishing to Azure portal the function endpoint returns "HTTP ERROR 500". It says <My_APP>.azurewebsites.net can't currently handle this request.

When I checked application insights for further log information I found below details.

`Result: Failure Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Dependency unixODBC with minimum version 2.3.1 is required. Unable to load shared library 'libodbc.so.2' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.8/libodbc.so.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /home/site/wwwroot/runtimes/linux/lib/net7.0/libodbc.so.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.8/liblibodbc.so.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /home/site/wwwroot/runtimes/linux/lib/net7.0/liblibodbc.so.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.8/libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /home/site/wwwroot/runtimes/linux/lib/net7.0/libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.8/liblibodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /home/site/wwwroot/runtimes/linux/lib/net7.0/liblibodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at FetchData() in C:\MY_PROJECT\MyFunction.cs:line 54`

May I ask to throw some light on how to troubleshoot or configure my function endpoint on azure portal?

I am very new to Azure infrastructure in terms of integrating, collaborating various components like Azure databricks. I greatly appreciate some insights here..

So far I have determined one thing that Azure Functions HTTP endpoints can communicate with Azure Databricks SQL tables and query them via ODBC driver.

What I am starting to think is as soon as I publish Azure Functions project and deploy to Azure portal, the same endpoints brings up HTTP 500 error. Meaning, between Azure Functions and Azure Databricks - that component I am missing.

Also, I have `host.json` file which might require some additional settings to support this connectivity.

Should I look into other Azure services like Azure SQL, Azure Data Factory, Azure Synapse which might be the gateway to Azure Databricks catalogs and I should be accessing them in Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have correct version of UnixODBC package installed - most probably you're using old Docker image or something like that (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76662265/how-to-include-simba-odbc-drivers-as-part-of-docker-file-for-local-testing-using/76736455#76736455)).

But really, for Azure Functions it's much more easier to use [SQL Statement Execution REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/statementexecution/executestatement) that doesn't need any external dependencies like ODBC drivers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for insight. I am using Azure App Service (Linux) and created Azure Function App built on it. Can you tell further if I can install unixODBC driver on Azure App Service?

Comment: Not sure, never used it.